# How to get all reviews from Trip advisor api

Tags: tripadvisor

I am wondering how to get all reviews for specific place, from Trip Advisor Api. For now my call is

```
http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/location/SOMEPLACEID?key=MYAPIKEY
```

But in location response I have only latest 3 reviews. How can I get them all?

```
"reviews": [{1},{2},{3}],

"num_reviews": "227",
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualified Content API users are limited to the display of the three most recent review snippets per location, no additional content is available. Visit TripAdvisor's Content API Developers Google Group to submit questions to their team and read FAQs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tripadvisor-api-dev